# how to connect eclipse with GTV device

Tags: android, google-tv

Simple but yet unanswered question:

Since GTV was announced we are trying to figure out how we are supposed to make apps. The current emulator is way too slow on our machines and as you can imagine we want to start this as soon as possible. So how can we connect eclipse with a GTV device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So how can we connect eclipse with a GTV device?

At the time of this writing, outside of a handful of development "fishtank" devices, there are no Google TV devices officially supported for development. If you have a "fishtank" device, I sure hope that they provided you instructions for using it for development, since that was the point. I was not one of the "fishtank" recipients, so I can't say for certain.

> The current emulator is way too slow on our machines

Really? I found the Google TV emulator to work astonishingly well, better than a regular Honeycomb ARM emulator. I haven't played with it a ton yet, but the KVM-based x86 virtualization works much better than I had expected. Admittedly, I'm running it on a Core i7 machine with Turbo Boost to 3.4GHz, which probably helps. If your issue is that you don't want to set up a Linux environment for it, [here are some instructions from another SO user](http://cubiclepi.com/2011/09/running-r1-google-tv-emulator-on-a-windows-pc-sorta/) for creating a bootable USB thumb drive with Ubuntu and the Google TV SDK environment.

If you are unwilling to use the emulator, I suggest that you simply wait a few more weeks until existing Google TV devices support development and the Market.

Comment: problem is that i have an amd/ati setup on the linux comp, so no kvm for me :(

Comment: @Alex: Ah. Well, um, I guess you're stuck waiting, then. You might find some hacks for getting apps to run on existing Google TV devices, but it will be the wrong OS version, and there might well be substantial differences between how it works now and how it will work when things are official. Sorry!

Comment: All Google TV devices on the market support development. The Honeycomb 3.1 update enabled all devices for development. If your device does not support development, it means that you did not accept the Honeycomb 3.1 update. The steps to connect from eclipse are given in @ssgg's answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can connect Eclipse to your GTV devices.  It's one of the questions answered during a Google TV developers hangout: http://goo.gl/DJpyx

How to set up development environment using Logitech Revue?

It's a 2-step process.

- Configure Google TV:

  - Settings -> Applications -> (enable) Unknown sources
  - Settings -> Applications -> Development -> (enable) Remote debugging
  - Settings -> Applications -> Development -> (add) Debugger IP address (of development box, see screenshots)
- Start adb on your dev box:

  - Connect to Google TV: adb connect xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (IP address of Google TV)
  - Check connected devices: adb devices
  - Install APK to Google TV: adb install [nameofyourapp.apk]
  - or Run directly from Eclipse, you may select your connected GTV as target

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Google TV emulator that is available for Linux with KVM extensions? The speed of that one is quite nice. It's fast enough for development for sure.

I hope it will be also released for Windows soon.